# Aliasing a namespaced route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces

Given the following routes.rb file:

```
# Add Admin section routes
 map.namespace :admin do |admin|
   admin.resources :admin_users
   admin.resources :admin_user_sessions, :as => :sessions
   admin.resources :dashboard

   # Authentication Elements
   admin.login '/login',  :controller => 'admin_user_sessions', :action => 'new'    
   admin.logout '/logout', :controller => 'admin_user_sessions', :action => 'destroy'

   # Default is login page for admin_users
   admin.root :controller => 'admin_user_sessions', :action => 'new'
end
```

Is it possible to alias the 'admin' section to something else without having to change every redirection and link_to in the application? The main reason is that it's something I'd like to be configurable on the fly and hopefully make it also a bit less easy to guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map.namespace` method just sets some common options for routes inside its block. It uses `with_options` method:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb, line 47
        def namespace(name, options = {}, &block)
          if options[:namespace]
            with_options({:path_prefix => "#{options.delete(:path_prefix)}/#{name}", :name_prefix => "#{options.delete(:name_prefix)}#{name}_", :namespace => "#{options.delete(:namespace)}#{name}/" }.merge(options), &block)
          else
            with_options({:path_prefix => name, :name_prefix => "#{name}_", :namespace => "#{name}/" }.merge(options), &block)
          end
        end
```

So it is possible to use `with_options` method directly instead of `namespace`:

```
map.with_options(:path_prefix => "yournewprefix", :name_prefix => "admin_", :namespace => "admin/" ) do |admin|  
  admin.resources :admin_users
  # ....
end
```

And you can continue to use routes the same way as before, but prefix will be "yournewprefix" instead of "admin"

```
admin_admin_users_path #=> /yournewprefix/admin_users
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to create an alias to the namespace (calling one `api_version` for example, from another router address) you can do the following:

```
#routes.rb
%w(v1 v2).each do |api_version|
  namespace api_version, api_version: api_version, module: :v1 do
    resources :some_resource
    #...
  end
end
```

this will cause the routes `/v1/some_resource` and `/v2/some_resource` to get to the same controller. then you can use `params[:api_version]` to get the evrsion you need and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Like in any other resource, :path seem to be working fine for me.

```
namespace :admin, :path => "myspace" do
  resources : notice 
    resources :article do 
      resources :links , :path => "url"
    end 
  end
end
```